# DLM, regression and multiple time series

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, autocorrelation, dlm

I'm working with incoming traffic data at multiple spots along a long road. Let's denote the traffic at time t at point $j$ by $x_j(t)$. For each spot, a univariate model, such as local level plus AR(1) is able to capture most variability in the timeseries. However, it seems natural that the information from point $x_j(t-1)$ should be used in someway to better predict $x_k(t)$ where $k$ is on the downstream of $j$. Cross correlation between $x_k$ and $x_j$ is a somewhat symmetric, with few (~5) significant lags. so, to predict $x_k(t)$, I used:
$$ x_k(t) = a_t + x_k(t-1) + \beta x_j(t-1)  + v_t$$ 
Now the problem is that the residuals become highly correlated (they were not before adding the regression term), and even adding AR(5) does not remove this correlation. Now given that I would like to use data from other points at the upstream of $x_k$ as well, one might think that this would only exacerbate the problem.

I want to model my series in state-space form, since it's good for adopting to real time data, as well as ease of introducing new variables.

I have two questions:

1. Is my approach adequate? By which I mean, does it make sense to include this effect as regression factor?
2. Should I change my approach, look into VARs, etc. ? In other words, what is the best approach to take in this problem?

I'm using R and DLM package, in case that matters.

Comment: Could you please prove this "Now the problem is that the residuals become highly correlated" as I routinely do not find this to be true . Please post your two data sets and the two models with parameters and the two sets of errors along with the ACF of these two error streams.